# Return true if two columns have intersected values

Tags: sql, intersection

I have two tables. I would like to return true if at least one value intersects:

`1,2,7` and `7,4,0` - 7 intersects, return `true`

`1,2,3` and `4,5,6` - no intersections, return `false`

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: what database is this? sql server/oracle/mysql? Please update the tags accordingly.

Comment: You have those data in row level as you have mentioned in your example or column  ??

Comment: column level values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct 'true'
from mytable
where column1 in (select column2 from mytable)
```

If there's a match, you'll get one row with 'true'.
If there's no match, you'll get no rows.

Answer (score 2):

try this, use inner join

`select case when exists (
   select 1 from TableA as A
      inner join TableB as B on B.colA = A.colA)
 then 'TRUE'
 else 'FALSE' end as 'Intersects'`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with a `full join` and conditional aggregation.

```
select max(case when t1.val=t2.val then 'true' else 'false' end) as intersect_or_no
from tbl1 t1
full join tbl2 t2 on t1.val=t2.val
```

Note: This won't work in MySQL as it doesn't support `full join`. The behavior can however be replicated.

Another way with `exists`.

```
SELECT coalesce(
              (SELECT 'true'
               FROM tbl1 t1
               WHERE EXISTS
                   (SELECT 1
                    FROM tbl2 t2
                    WHERE t1.val=t2.val)),'false') AS intersect_or_no
```